# On Going notification on Android Wear

Tags: android, wear-os

I'm trying to make an Android Wear notification to work with my app, and I want it to be Ongoing.

When using setOnGoing, the notification not displayed on the watch.

But I'm sure it's possible, because the google cast notification of youtube cannot be dismissed on the watch.

Can you help? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to show ongoing notifications on Andorid Wear, but NOT from phone (ongoing notifications posted FROM phone won't be shown on watch). It means you need to create a wearable extension to your app and post notification directly from Android Wear device.

So, from Android Wear you can just post a normal ongoing notification and it will be displayed on watch - like you see in some other apps. This is the only way to display an ongoing notifications on Android Wear.

If you want to display an ongoing notification on watch and ongoing notification on phone - you will need to synchronize them. For this purpose there is a great wearable `DataApi`.

Please read more about `DataApi` here:
https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/index.html
https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/data-items.html

You can also take a look at my post where I've posted a code demonstrating how to use `DataApi` in practise:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/24896043/3827276

Comment: You said I need to synchronize the notifications, and I did a wearable-extended notification, but still I can't find a way to make it ongoing. The extender has no setOnGoing method.

Comment: As I said - from Android Wear device post a NORMAL notification. Use standard `setOngoing(true)` method.

Comment: When I'm using the standard method, the notification is not displayed on the watch.

Comment: Are you 100% sure that you're trying to post this notification FROM Android Wear device (and NOT from phone)? I doubt so.

Comment: Wait. You mean to create an Android Wear App that posts notifications?

Comment: Yes, please read my answer one more time.