# Sync data to watch from phone

Tags: android, android-wear-data-api

I made my own watchface and now I want to add the phones battery percentage too the watchface along with being able to customize he watchface from the phone.  I'm trying to use this:[Android Wear Watchface Settings on host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24894711/android-wear-watchface-settings-on-host) but I keep getting errors.

```
Unknown entity 'connection callbacks' 

Method
com.google.android.gems.common.Api.GoggleApiClient.builder.addConnectioncallbacks(com.google.android.gems.common.Api.GoggleApiClient.builder.Connectioncallbacks)'in
com.google.android.gems.common.Api.GoggleApiClient.Builder' connot be applied to '(com.example.android.wearable.embedded.app.WatchfaceConfigActivity.(anonymous) )'

Unknown entity ''OnConnectionFailedListene'

Method
com.google.android.gems.common.Api.GoggleApiClient.builder.addOnConnectionFailedListener(com.google.android.gems.common.Api.GoggleApiClient.builder.OnConnectionFailedListener)'in
com.google.android.gems.common.Api.GoggleApiClient.Builder' connot be applied to '(com.example.android.wearable.embedded.app.WatchfaceConfigActivity.(anonymous) )'
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  I had to add the import for each of those.

I am still having an issue tho.  I'm very new to android development by the way.  I get a warning : there is no access to variable 'phonebattery'.  I replaced 'mode'  with 'phonebattery' from you answer here : [Android Wear Watchface Settings on host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24894711/android-wear-watchface-settings-on-host)