# Show a notification only on the wearable device

Tags: java, android, notifications, wear-os

I have an application with an ongoing `notification`. That `notification` doesn't show on the `wearable device` so I would like to add a new one only for the watch.

I tried give it a group but to access the `action buttons` I have to click the `notification` before swiping to the left which is not very handy...

Do you have any idea of what I should do ?

Comment: The fun thing is that if the notification is both in a group and ongoing it doesn't show on either of the devices...

Comment: Please see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24916387/3827276

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I'll try your second solution since I don't like having to click the grouped notification to get the action buttons.

Comment: No problem:) But you don't really need to have multiple items in a "group". You can do the trick with just "one" notification in group. Just use different group name for every ongoing notification:) You will have exactly two notifications in a group, one wearable notification (non-summary - will appear only on watch) and the ongoing notification (summary - will be shown on phone only)

Comment: Yes, but when I have only one notification in a group I can't swipe to the left to see the action buttons, I have to select it like when there are multiple notifications :/

Comment: Yes, you are right. This is the downside of using notifications group :(