# How to open the main app from the wearable?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-notifications, android-pendingintent, wear-os

I'm playing a little with wearables, I already created notifications from my micro app (which runs **on the wearable**) [with some little restrictions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25885364/995926) and I'm wondering how I can create a pending intent for an action to open the main app on the phone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My solution that I've just tested and it works is add a message listener on the Android application and simply send from the wearable the details of what I want it to do.

```
public class WearMessagesAPI_Service
        extends WearableListenerService {


    private static final String OPEN_APP_PATH = "/OpenApp";

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(MessageEvent event) {
        Log.w("WearMessagesAPI_Service", event.getPath());
        String activityKey = new String(event.getData());
        if(activityKey.equals(...)) {
            Intent myAppIntent = ... create intent ...
            startActivity(myAppIntent);
        }
    }
}
```

Don't forget to add it to your manifest:

```
<service android:name=".wearable.WearMessagesAPI_Service">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.wearable.BIND_LISTENER"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

And I believe that is it.
Let me know how it goes :)

Comment: Ah I remember now my problem. The WearableListenerService is part of the play services wearable library. Are you sure that it is possible to use it on a normal mobile? Well the minSdkVersion is 9, so it could work.

Comment: The minimum API 20 is to run the wearable on the wearable device. You can use the **WearableListenerService** in your phone app if you use the **com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.71** library which includes some of the wearable classes.

Comment: @TacB0sS do you have an example project? I am having trouble with the code. What is this condition supposed to be? `activityKey.equals(...)`

Answer (score 6):

I don't know if there is another way.

However it can work.
You build a notification in your wear module whick launches a Broadcast in the wear.
The broadcast (which runs on the wear) uses the *Message.API* to send a message to the mobile module.
On the mobile module there is a **`WearableListenerService`** which launches the MainActivity on mobile.

In your **Wear** build the notification:

```
 // Notification
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                                //.setContentTitle(mNotificationUtil.getTitle())
                        .setContentText("Text")
                        .setContentIntent(getPendingIntent(this));

        // Get an instance of the NotificationManager service
        NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager =
                NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);

        // Build the notification and issues it with notification manager.
        notificationManager.notify(1, notificationBuilder.build());

    }

    private PendingIntent getPendingIntent(MainActivity mainActivity) {
        final String INTENT_ACTION = "it.gmariotti.receiver.intent.action.TEST";

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(INTENT_ACTION);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent =
                PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        return pendingIntent;
    }
```

This notification launches a Broadcast message.
Declare this broadcast in your wear/AndroidManifest.xml

**wear/AndroidManifes.xml**

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" 
          android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />


 <receiver android:name=".MyBroadcast">
         <intent-filter>
              <action android:name="it.gmariotti.receiver.intent.action.TEST"/>
         </intent-filter>
 </receiver>
```

**Then implement the Broadcast to send the Message:**

```
public class MyBroadcast extends BroadcastReceiver implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    Node mNode; // the connected device to send the message to
    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private static final String WEAR_PATH = "/hello-world-wear";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        //Connect the GoogleApiClient
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context)
                .addApi(Wearable.API)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();

        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }
    /**
     * Send message to mobile handheld
     */
    private void sendMessage() {

        if (mNode != null && mGoogleApiClient!=null && mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            Wearable.MessageApi.sendMessage(
                    mGoogleApiClient, mNode.getId(), WEAR_PATH, null).setResultCallback(

                    new ResultCallback<MessageApi.SendMessageResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResult(MessageApi.SendMessageResult sendMessageResult) {

                            if (!sendMessageResult.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                                Log.e("TAG", "Failed to send message with status code: "
                                        + sendMessageResult.getStatus().getStatusCode());
                            }
                        }
                    }
            );
        }else{
            //Improve your code
        }

    }

    /*
     * Resolve the node = the connected device to send the message to
     */
    private void resolveNode() {

        Wearable.NodeApi.getConnectedNodes(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<NodeApi.GetConnectedNodesResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(NodeApi.GetConnectedNodesResult nodes) {
                for (Node node : nodes.getNodes()) {
                    mNode = node;
                }
                sendMessage();
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        resolveNode();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        //Improve your code
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        //Improve your code
    }
}
```

This code will send a Message to your mobile phone.
It requires in your **wear/build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
    compile "com.google.android.support:wearable:1.0.+"
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:+'
}
```

**On the **Mobile module** you have to implement a `WearableListenerService`**

```
/**
 * @author Gabriele Mariotti (gabri.mariotti@gmail.com)
 */
public class ListenerServiceFromWear extends WearableListenerService {

    private static final String WEAR_PATH = "/hello-world-wear";

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(MessageEvent messageEvent) {

        /*
         * Receive the message from wear
         */
        if (messageEvent.getPath().equals(WEAR_PATH)) {

            Intent startIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            startIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(startIntent);
        }    
    }    
}
```

It requires in your **Mobile/AndroidManifest.xml** to declare the Service.

```
<service android:name=".ListenerServiceFromWear">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.wearable.BIND_LISTENER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

and this **mobile/build.gradle** dependency:

```
dependencies {
    wearApp project(':wear')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:+'
}
```

Comment: How should this been possible? I cannot access the MainActivity class from the wearable, that is a differnt apk file.

Comment: You can create the notification in the mobile app.
Are you creating the notification only in the wear app?

Comment: Yes in this special case I'm talking about creating notifications *for* the wearable *on* the wearable.

Comment: Ok, in this case you have to use a Intent which send a Message (using the MessageAPI Wearable.MessageApi.sendMessage). In the mobile app you have to implement a WearableListenerService that listens for the message and launches the MainActivity.

Comment: So I can implement a `WearableListenerService` on the phone too? I was not sure about this point.

Comment: That would be great however I'm sure that there is some special intent which does that automatically. I think I need to hook the notifications on the wearable to get that intent I want to know.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti do you have an example project? I'm having trouble getting this code to work in Android Studio. Where do we put the `// Notification` code in the first code block?