# Group notifications on a wearable from the micro app

Tags: android, android-notifications, wear-os

I build a micro app for a wearable now I'm working with notifications on the device.

Here is my example code:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
        .setContentTitle(title)
        .setContentText(message)
        .setSmallIcon(icon)
        .setGroup(groupKey);

NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);
notificationManager.notify(id, builder.build());
```

This notification is never shown and it does not matter if I have one or multiple notifications with the same group key. Do you know what I'm doing wrong?

---

Just for clarification I striped down my Activity to this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle("title")
            .setContentText("message")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setGroup("groupKey");
    notificationManager.notify(111, builder.build());

    builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle("title2")
            .setContentText("message2")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setGroup("groupKey");
    notificationManager.notify(222, builder.build());
}
```

If those `.setGroup("groupKey")` lines are inside the wearable app (on the wearable) no notifications are visible. If I remove them the notifications are visible (ungrouped of cause). That does not work for me on the Samsung Gear Live (Android 4.4W.1) and the emulator (Android 4.4W).

Comment: I assume that you invoke this code from your wearable device? For me, this code is OK and the notification is shown on the wearable device emulator.

Comment: Yes I run that on the wearable, I just wrapped that code in a custom Builder, but I tried it on a real device. There is that 4.4w.1 running, I guess the emulator use still the old os

Comment: "I just wrapped that code in a custom Builder" ??? Can you please post some more code of your "custom Builder"? Maybe problem lies there and not in this code you've posted. BTW. Have you tested this code on emulator? and it works there?

Comment: I just tried it in the emulator, and it does not work there too. The Builder I'm using is just a wraper for simplify things like setting the background image define that actions etc. I can do that now in one line. However since that code above does not work on the emulator too that is not related at all.

Comment: There is no reason why this code should not work. I have tested it and the code is OK. 1. Please invoke ONLY this few lines of code - without ANYTHING else and test if it works. The error is somewhere else, because this code is 100% correct. 2. Please check if your app is not muted in the "Android Wear" companion app. Then any notification will not be shown on watch.

Comment: I already checked that I broke it down to that lines above just for beeing sure, my app is also not blocked. I'm getting other notifications.

Comment: 1. Does only a "group" notifications not work? 2. Are you 100% sure that this code is actually being invoked? 3. Please create an empty main `Activity` and post only this few lines in `onCreate()` method. 4. Use hardcoded values for `title`, `message` and `icon` and make sure that resource for `setSmallIcon` is different than `0`. In documentation about notifications there is said that `smallIcon` is mandatory, so any notification without `smallIcon` wont be displayed at all.

Comment: Yes and again yes see my update.

Comment: As I said - the code works perfectly for me... This is the result of launching an `Activity` with your exact (without ANY change): http://i.stack.imgur.com/oe5Ml.png

Comment: Try this code snippet and see if it works for you https://gist.github.com/waynepiekarski/775dcd9105bd5c376eb4 ... this code definitely works. If it fails for you, it means something is wrong with your device or perhaps you don't have notification bridging enabled.

Comment: I'll check that tomorrow, but why is bridging required? I create the notification already on the wearable...